# PHP Compare File Timestamp to check if it should be overwritten

Tags: php, file, datetime, timestamp

I am building myself a CSS file concatenator, and want to be able to specify a number of minutes to hold the concatenated file from being overwritten.

If it is past that many minutes old it should be overwritten.

Here is my code

```
$_file = "/my/valid/file/location.css"

$_numberofminutes = 5;

$_ftime = filemtime( $_file ); // returns me an integer of the last modified date
$_ctime = strtotime( '+' . $_numberofminutes . ' minutes' ); // returns me NOW +5 minutes

if( ( $_ftime >= $_ctime ) ) {
    var_dump( 'overwrite' );
}
```

And no matter how long I wait, I never see the `overwrite`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What happens if you echo $_ftime and $_ctime

Comment: Why would $_ftime be greater than **current time + 5 minutes** . This condition will never come true. File modification time can at max be current time. You cant get future time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it backwards.

`$_ctime` will always be a time in the future.
And because of that `$_ftime` will never be larger.

You should add the five minutes to `$_ftime` not `$_ctime`.

And that means you also need to change `>=` to `<=`

Comment: thanks Andreas.  Sometimes this side of the week, my brain cells need a kick